# Invalid output in python: SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute the following code and expected to get the result of the new age. But instead, I got a syntax error. Here is my code:

```py
age = input('Enter your age:')
new_age = int age + 10**2
print(new_age)
```

And here is the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what does the syntax error point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move int:

```py
age = int(input('enter age'))
new_age = age + 10**2
print(new_age)
```

You can also do as Tomerikoo said:

```py
new_age = int(age) + 10**2
```

Either one works :)

Comment: Rereading. Clarification: int, float, ord, bin, oct, etc. are functions *not* statements, so you have to have the parenthesis. Sorry for not being clear :/

Answer (score 2):

I'm only a noob, but you need parentheses "()" around the word 'age' in your int statement
new_age=int(age)+10**2

Answer (score 1):

well, if you want to convert `age` to an [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), you do it by:

```py
new_age = int(age) + 10**2
```

Or better yet:

```py
age = int(input('Enter your age:'))
```

what you have right now: `int age` is a `SyntaxError`